# Java Applet Pong game if statement doesn't stop

Tags: java, netbeans, applet

I'm trying to make this game in java applet i have done everything but the only problem is when someone loses (like the player or pc) when the ball comes out of the "screen" displays my dialog with "game over". But it always shows it to me and does not close or take it from the end ..

```
package pongproiect;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

/**
 *
 * @author negruandrei
 */
public class Tennis extends Applet implements Runnable, KeyListener{
    final int WIDTH=700, HEIGHT=500;
    Thread thread;
    Player1Paddle p1;
    Player2Paddle p2; //de adaugat player2
    PCPaddle pcp;
    Ball b1;
    int restart = 250;
    boolean gameStarted; 
    int p1score=0, p2score=0;


    public void init(){
            this.resize(WIDTH,HEIGHT);
            this.addKeyListener(this);
            gameStarted = false;
            // gamePause = false;
            p1 = new Player1Paddle(1);
            b1 = new Ball();
            p2 = new Player2Paddle(2); //de adaugat player2
            pcp = new PCPaddle(2, b1);

            thread = new Thread(this);
            thread.start();
}
    public void paint(Graphics g){


        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);


         if(b1.getX()< -10 || b1.getX()> 710){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Game Over boy!");



         }


         if(!gameStarted){
             g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
             g.drawString("Press Enter to start", 290, 150);
         }
             g.setColor(Color.white);
            // g.drawString("Score Player1 : " + p1score, 300, 475); //nefunctionabil
            // g.drawString("Score Player2 : " + p2score, 300, 490); //nefunctionabil
             p1.draw(g);
             b1.draw(g);
             pcp.draw(g);
             // p2.draw(g); -> de adaugat player2


    }

    public void update(Graphics g){
        paint(g);
    }




    public void run() {
        while(true){

           if(gameStarted){ 
            //p2.move(); -> de adaugat player2
            b1.move();
            p1.move();
            pcp.move();
            b1.checkPaddleCollision(p1, pcp);
            p1score=0;
            p2score=0;   
           }
            repaint(); 
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }


    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e ) {
        switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
            case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                p1.setupAccel(true);
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                p1.setdownAccel(true);
                break;
             //de adaugat player2
           /* case KeyEvent.VK_W:
                p2.setupAccel(true);
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_S:
                p2.setdownAccel(true);
                break; */
            case KeyEvent.VK_ENTER:
                gameStarted = true; 
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
            case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                p1.setupAccel(false);
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                p1.setdownAccel(false);
                break;

                //de adaugat player2
           /* case KeyEvent.VK_W:
                p2.setupAccel(true);
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_S:
                p2.setdownAccel(true);
                break; */
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

Player 1 paddle

```
package pongproiect;

import java.awt.*;
/**
 *
 * @author negruandrei
 */
public class Player1Paddle implements Paddle {
    double y, yVel;
    boolean upAccel, downAccel;
    int player, x; 
    final double GRAVITY =0.94;


    public Player1Paddle (int player) {

    upAccel=false; downAccel=false;
    y=210; yVel=0;


    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(20, (int)y, 20, 80);
    }


    public void move() {
        if(upAccel){
            yVel -=2;
        }
        else if(downAccel){
            yVel +=2;
        }
        else if(!upAccel && !downAccel){
             yVel *=GRAVITY;
        }
        if(yVel >= 3){
            yVel=3;
        }
        else if (yVel <=-3){
            yVel=-3;
        }
        if (y < 0){
            y =0;
        }
        if (y > 420){
            y=420;
        }

        y += yVel;
    }

    public void setupAccel (boolean input){
        upAccel = input;
    }
    public void setdownAccel (boolean input){
        downAccel = input;
    }


    public int getY() {
        return (int)y;
    }

}
```

Player 2 paddle

```
package pongproiect;


import java.awt.*;
/**
 *
 * @author negruandrei
 */

    public class Player2Paddle implements Paddle {
        double y, yVel;
        boolean upAccel, downAccel;
        int player, x; 
        final double GRAVITY =0.94;


        public Player2Paddle (int player) {

        upAccel=false; downAccel=false;
        y=210; yVel=0;

        if(player == 1)
            x = 20;
         else 
            x = 660;


        }

        public void draw(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.fillRect(660, (int)y, 20, 80);
        }


        public void move() {
            if(upAccel){
                yVel -=2;
            }
            else if(downAccel){
                yVel +=2;
            }
            else if(!upAccel && !downAccel){
                 yVel *=GRAVITY;
            }
            if(yVel >= 3){
                yVel=3;
            }
            else if (yVel <=-3){
                yVel=-3;
            }
            if (y < 0){
                y =0;
            }
            if (y > 420){
                y=420;
            }

            y += yVel;
        }

        public void setupAccel (boolean input){
            upAccel = input;
        }
        public void setdownAccel (boolean input){
            downAccel = input;
        }


        public int getY() {
            return (int)y;
        }

    }
```

Paddle

```
package pongproiect;

import java.awt.Graphics;
/**
 *
 * @author negruandrei
 */
public interface Paddle {
    public void draw(Graphics g);
    public void move();
    public int getY();


}
```

PCPADDLE

```
package pongproiect;

import java.awt.*;
/**
 *
 * @author negruandrei
 */
public class PCPaddle implements Paddle {
    double y, yVel;
    boolean upAccel, downAccel;
    int player, x; 
    final double GRAVITY =0.94;
    Ball b1;


    public PCPaddle (int player, Ball b) {

    upAccel=false; downAccel=false;
    y=210; yVel=0;
    b1 = b;

    if(player == 1)
        x = 20;
     else 
        x = 660;


    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(x, (int)y, 20, 80);
    }


    public void move() {
        y = b1.getY() - 40;


        if (y < 0){
            y =0;
        }
        if (y > 420){
            y=420;
        }

        y += yVel;
    }


    public int getY() {
        return (int)y;
    }

}
```

Ball

```
package pongproiect;
import java.awt.*;

/**
 *
 * @author negruandrei
 */
public class Ball {
    double x, y, xVel, yVel;


    public Ball(){
        x=350;
        y=250;
        xVel= getRandomSpeed() *getRandomDirection();
        yVel= getRandomSpeed() *getRandomDirection();
    }

    public double getRandomSpeed(){
        return (Math.random() *2 + 2);
    }
    public int getRandomDirection(){
        int dir = (int)(Math.random()*2);
        if (dir == 1)
            return 1;
        else
            return -1;
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g){
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillOval((int)x-10, (int)y-10, 20, 20);

    }

    public void checkPaddleCollision(Paddle p1, Paddle p2){
     if(x<=50){
         if(y >= p1.getY() && y <= p1.getY() +80)
             xVel = -xVel;
     }
     else if(x>=650){
         if(y >= p2.getY() && y <= p2.getY() +80)
             xVel = -xVel;
     }
}

    public void move(){
        x += xVel;
        y += yVel;

        if( y<10 ){
            yVel= -yVel;
            }
        if( y>490 ){
            yVel= -yVel;
            }

}

    public int getX(){
        return (int)x;
    }
    public int getY(){
        return (int)y;
    }
```

}

Comment: Where exactly is the statement you are having issue with?  Thats a lot of code to look through.

Comment: @Nexevis here  "if(b1.getX()< -10 || b1.getX()> 710){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Game Over boy!");



         }"

Comment: And just for the record: you know that Applets in Java are dead since many years, and learning how to use them is like learning how to outrun a Tyrannosaurus Rex? (maybe interesting and challenging, but not of any value in the real world out there)

Comment: And regarding question style: please keep [mcve] in mind all the time. Dont paste all your code, try to identify the relevant parts. Then: avoid all these pointless empty lines in your code. Each and any character is in your code because you want to be there. Empty lines are *only* used to group things vertically.